# How it can be legal to pass a variable with a data type to a function?

Tags: c++, pointers, types, reference, arguments

I am currently examining DLL to a very specific measurement device which is called "force plate" and produced by Advanced Mechanical Technology, Inc. It measures ground reaction forces generated by a human standing or moving across them. This DLL is written in Visual C++ (as programmers reference says) and provided by manufacturer of force plate.

So, there is a function which is called `fmDLLTransferFloatData`. This is how it is declared in DLL's header file:

`int DLLExport fmDLLTransferFloatData(float *&data);`

It returns an `int` and requires a reference to a pointer to `float` data. So far so good. And here comes the strange part of this function, the way it must be used in a code according to programmers reference:

```
float *ptr;
int ret;

//getting the Data
ret = fmDLLTransferFloatData((float *&)ptr);
```

Take a look at the argument syntaxis: `((float *&)ptr)`. And it works. Can someone explain what does this syntaxis actually means?

So, as I've already said, this function works fine, I am actually will be very glad if someone explain this weird syntaxis to me.

Comment: The `(float *&)` part is a C-style *cast*, it's a conversion. And that conversion should not be needed if your argument already is a `float *`. In fact, C-style casts like that should be avoided at almost all costs. If you ever feel the need to make one then you should take that as a sign that you're probably doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `(T)E` where `T` is a type and `E` an expression is a C-style cast or explicit type conversion. It converts the expression `E` to the type `T`. Of all of C++'s cast expressions, it is the one that permits the largest set of conversions.

However, It does absolutely nothing with the context you are showing. If `ptr` is a variable of type `float*` then the expressions `ptr` and `(float *&)ptr` are 100% exactly equivalent.

So you can just write `ptr` instead.

In fact, using the C-style cast `(float *&)` is a bad practice since it can easily cause serious problems to go unnoticed. The cast will almost always succeed, regardless of what type `ptr` is, but if it isn't actually `float*`, then it will almost surely cause undefined behavior. However a compiler won't diagnose this as an error or warning, because the cast essentially tells the compiler to just do it without complaining, no matter how dangerous it may be.

There is almost never a need to use C-style casts in C++. C++ has `static_cast`, `const_cast` and `reinterpret_cast` instead, each of which permits only a smaller subset of conversions and are therefore more specific and safer to use. In most cases `static_cast` is sufficient to replace C-style casts and in other cases extra care must be taken.

Comment: Agree about the C style casting points but it is not the same. It allows the called function to change the ptr to the float. [See this](https://godbolt.org/z/avbxaqnjG)

Comment: Perhaps the cast is to make it clearer to the user of the function that the pointer itself can be altered by the function? One of the reasons I prefer double ptrs when the function is altering the pointer. Rare fortunately.

Comment: @doug There would be no difference in your example either if you replaced `(float*&)ptr` with `ptr`. Both are lvalues of the same type referring to the same object.

Comment: @doug This is not a good approach to indicating out parameters. It may suppress errors/warnings from mistakes but doesn't cause the compiler to provide any additional diagnostics in any situation.

Comment: It's a visual indicator that the called function can change the pointer. No actual functionality. Not sure what other reason the library author would say to do this.

Comment: @doug In that case it would be much better to define a macro or identity function to either place before or around the argument. It also functionally wouldn't do anything, but at least wouldn't hide mistakes by suppressing the type system.

Comment: My first comment was simply wrong suggesting it changed the call. It does not.. upvoting.

Comment: First of all thank you for your great answers. I've tried using just `ptr` instead of `(float *&)ptr` and it woks just fine. And, yes, this function alters the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @user17732522's comments I've corrected some things in the answer. and hopefully explained things in more detail.

The following are identical because an expression automatically converts an lvalue into a reference to an lvalue.

```
ret = fmDLLTransferFloatData((float *&)ptr);
ret = fmDLLTransferFloatData((float *)ptr);
ret = fmDLLTransferFloatData(ptr);
```

Further, these calls would also all work identically and pass by value instead were the function declared:

```
int fmDLLTransferFloatData(float *);
```

instead of:

```
int fmDLLTransferFloatData(float *&);
```

The only possible reason the DLL library coder could suggest using the first version is to "document" that `ptr` itself is subject to modification in the  DLL function. But it does not enforce it. Rather it's more akin to a comment.

This line indicates the called function to alter the pointer, not just the float being pointed to.

```
ret = fmDLLTransferFloatData((float *&)ptr);
```

Example code showing the pointer is altered:

```
#include <iostream>
float other_float = 42;
float orig{ 1 };
float* ptr{ &orig };

int fmDLLTransferFloatData(float*& ptr)
{
    ptr = &other_float;
    return 2;
}

//getting the Data
int main()
{
    int ret;
    std::cout << *ptr << '\n';
    ret = fmDLLTransferFloatData((float*&)ptr);
    std::cout << *ptr << '\n';
    return ret;
}
```

[Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/avbxaqnjG)

It's unnecessary to even have the cast if the function is properly declared:

```
int fmDLLTransferFloatData(float *&);
```

It can then be called w/o the cast:

```
 ret = fmDLLTransferFloatData(ptr);
```

Comment: "_It's unnecessary to even have the cast if the function is properly declared:_": Without the proper declaration the call has undefined behavior regardless of the cast. The cast doesn't create a reference. References exist only as declared entities. The result of an expression can't be or refer to a reference. Expressions naming references are lvalue expressions, the result of which will refer to the object bound to the reference. In particular a variadic function can't take an argument by reference, regardless of such a cast.

Comment: @user17732522 Yeah, Agree. The only reason I see is to make it clear to the coder that the pointer is an `out` variable. I hate references as out function parameters. Using `*` doesn't obscure like references do.